# Pages generated with interesting keywords

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, hyperlinks

As I searched for new links on QR Code I found that stackoverflow "generate" pages with strong keywords in the title.
My original question is [How to soften edges of an image programmatically with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975873/how-to-soften-edges-of-an-image-programmatically-with-php) and the generated page from my question is [qr code with soft edge](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:uUDAIfUZIYkJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/6975873/qr-code-with-soft-edge%20qr%20code%20soft%20edge&cd=3&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr&source=www.google.fr).

How do they do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Through the magic of human intervention: Your question title was [edited by another user](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6975873/revisions).

[image]